# Open a rating screen after 3 times opening app wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup

I have a popup rating screen where users can rate the app. After opening the app 3 times I want to show this popup rating screen. How can I open a popup after 3 times opening the app?

Answer (score 2):

Store a counter in the usersettings and each time the app opens, increment and save the settings.
On the mainwindow.loaded do a check on the usersettings, if the counter > 3 then launch a new dialog window with your rating application. (Or any other possible implementation of showing a popup.)